# collapsing optgroups that contain all unchecked options in boostrap-multiselect

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect, optgroup

I am using boostrap-multiselect for my application. The select box contains three optgroups. Whenever I click on some checkbox in it, I want to collapse the optgroups once I switch to another optgroup.

Here is the sample code

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="food_type">
    <optgroup label="Breakfast">
        <option value="Burger">Burger</option>
        <option value="Fries">Fries</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Lunch">
        <option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
        <option value="Thali">Thali</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Desserts">
        <option value="Icecreame">Icecreame</option>
        <option value="Fruit Salad">Fruit Salad</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

$("#food_type").multiselect({
    numberDisplayed: 1,
    buttonText: function (options, select){
        return "Food Types";
    },
    enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
    collapseOptGroupsByDefault: true
});
```

By default all optgroups are collapsed. I want to toggle the collapse-expand of optgroups once I switched to another optgroup for selection.

I couldn't find default functionality provided in documentation of bootstrap-mulitselect. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> By default all optgroups are collapsed. I want to toggle the collapse-expand of optgroups once I switched to another optgroup for selection.

You can attach the click event handler to each **multiselect-group** elements. Inside this you can toggle the visibility of the others optgroups.

```js
$("#food_type").multiselect({
    numberDisplayed: 1,
    buttonText: function (options, select) {
        return "Food Types";
    },
    enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
    collapseOptGroupsByDefault: true
}).data('multiselect').$ul.find('.multiselect-group').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.multiselect-group').nextUntil('.multiselect-group')
            .addClass('multiselect-collapsible-hidden').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <select multiple="multiple" id="food_type">
            <optgroup label="Breakfast">
                <option value="Burger">Burger</option>
                <option value="Fries">Fries</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Lunch">
                <option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
                <option value="Thali">Thali</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Desserts">
                <option value="Icecreame">Icecreame</option>
                <option value="Fruit Salad">Fruit Salad</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead, if you need to toggle all the optgroups containing all unchecked options you can test it inside the click event handler:

```js
$("#food_type").multiselect({
numberDisplayed: 1,
buttonText: function (options, select) {
return "Food Types";
},
enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
collapseOptGroupsByDefault: true
}).data('multiselect').$ul.find('.multiselect-group').on('click', function (e) {
  $(this).siblings('.multiselect-group').each(function(idx, ele) {
      var eles = $(ele).nextUntil('.multiselect-group');
      if (eles.find(':checked').length == 0) {
          eles.addClass('multiselect-collapsible-hidden').hide();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <select multiple="multiple" id="food_type">
            <optgroup label="Breakfast">
                <option value="Burger">Burger</option>
                <option value="Fries">Fries</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Lunch">
                <option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
                <option value="Thali">Thali</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Desserts">
                <option value="Icecreame">Icecreame</option>
                <option value="Fruit Salad">Fruit Salad</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```